# To parse JSON data from text file using c# winforms

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I have numbers of text files containing Json data, i want to parse all required data from all those files. I am creating C# windows app to do this task.
please help me for same, thanx a lot in advance

Here is my text file data sample:

```
Name: sample testname
Username: sampleXYZ
Time zone: SampleTimezone
Language: EN
Json: {
  "id": 600723423551234234234,
  "id_str": "600723423551234234234",
  "name": "sample testname",
  "screen_name": "sampleXYZ",
  "location": "sample Location",
  "description": "sampleDescritpin",
  "url": null,
  "entities": {       "description": {
  "urls": []
    }
  },
     //some unwanted data in between 
        }
```

Comment: What is the nature of the unwanted data?  Is it part of the JSON, or is it something else that has been stuck into the JSON and doesn't conform to the standard?  Also, is there anything that comes after the JSON in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to extract the JSON from your file; to do this you could do something like this:

```
static string ExtractJSON(string path)
{
    var file = File.ReadAllText(path);
    var brackets = 0;
    var json = "";

    foreach (var c in file)
    {
        if (c == '{') // if { encountered, go in a level
            brackets++;
        else if (c == '}') // if } encountered go out a level
        {
            brackets--;
            if (brackets == 0) 
                json += c.ToString(); // get the last bracket
        }

        if (brackets > 0) // ignore everything that isn't within the brackets
            json += c.ToString();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Then once you have your json data, use a parser like the one by NewtonSoft to parse the json